# Default Sound configuration

Tags: sound, configuration

On Ubuntu 15.10, why is the default input sound device an open microphone?  The microphone should be used only when recording, not for general use. Is Ubuntu into the business of leaving open back doors to violate our assumed 
privacy?

For anyone  who  cares about his/her privacy, this default configuration 
should not be OK.

I have not used Ubuntu for  sometime now. Is the accepted default configuration?

Comment: Can you show me what testing you did that shows the mic is open at all times?

Comment: On a fresh Installation: step 1 Open sound configuration tool. This shows the microphone as the only input sound device (not muted)  2.  aplay   /usr/share/.../soundfile.wav

Comment: This doesn't prove it is listening at all times.  When the program is opened it could initialize the device.  What proof do you have that the mic is in fact listening at all times?

Comment: I never said it is listening at all times.  The potential for someone to license is obvious.  The real issue here is why the microphone  is the default input device(if in fact it is)? Why would a configuration tool show the mic to be opened if  it was  not ?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu recognizes your Mic as an input device so applications can use it properly.  This is how operating systems work.  They create interfaces to interact with.

I am not sure what you are getting at in terms of privacy, but it is not a concern as you are in control of your computer and what applications you install.

If you are worried an application will listen in to your MIC without your permission then you probably shouldn't install it, or at the very least do a security audit.

I encourage your privacy conscious behavior.  It is most welcome in the Linux community.  One thing that is not really acceptable in this case is making accusations, or crying foul without having proof.  In other words if you are curious about something just ask about it, but if you do not know then I would just suggest you frame something you are worried about in the form of a question so you get a better response.

You can also disable your MIC if you wish.

```
alsamixer
```

But to answer your question, yes this is an acceptable configuration though.

Comment: I believe my post was in the form of a question. Take a fresh look.  What I am alluding to happened to me. So, I  reserve to right to inquiry.

Comment: Let's not rival over this issue.  And I wish to say thank you Goddard for your timely responses.

Comment: I do wish applications where slightly more locked down and required permissions to do certain things.  I also wish more applications were in a jail/container.  I think the later might have more push back due to drive space requirements for such a system, but generally speaking it isn't a security concern because you can disable it.